# I cant get page's html code by get method Python, requests. get method returns some strange code

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Sorry for my bad english

I am still learning

i have this code

```
import requests
import os

os.system('CLS')

r = requests.get('https://kazanexpress.ru/product/736692')
with open('file.html','w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
```

So in file.html i got that

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=ru><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"><meta http-equiv=content-language content=ru><meta name=description content="Маркетплейс выгодных цен с бесплатной доставкой за сутки."><meta name=keywords content="маркетплейс, интернет-магазин, доставка на следующий день, низкие цены, купить дешево, быстрая доставка, лучшие цены"><meta id=prerender-status-code name=prerender-status-code content=200><meta id=prerender-header name=prerender-header content=""><title>KazanExpress - шопинг с бесплатной доставкой за 1 день</title><link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=32x32 href=/static/img/icons/favicon-32.png><link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=16x16 href=/static/img/icons/favicon-16.png><meta name=ROBOTS content="INDEX, FOLLOW"><meta property=og:url content=""><meta property=og:title content=""><meta property=og:description content=""><meta property=og:image itemprop=image content=""><meta property=og:image:secure_url content=""><meta property=og:type content=website><meta property=product:brand content=""><meta property=product:availability content=""><meta property=product:condition content=new><meta property=product:price:amount content=""><meta property=product:retailer_item_id content=""><meta property=product:price:currency content=RUB><link rel=canonical href=https://kazanexpress.ru/ ><link itemprop=thumbnailUrl href=url_image><meta name=twitter:image content=""><meta name=apple-itunes-app content="app-id=1438104323"><meta name=facebook-domain-verification content=rb1tipol8glrbndktmbkyom0xaqomi><meta name=google-site-verification content=ffMsQuJJt9A3n3pN6FcpIKq8UcuWj1gvjMdvqLxEwMI><meta name=google-site-verification content=QrVT-SLKbPGSA5shhmMLeS9ilfJ-V7IoNDb3pxgHvt4><meta name=google-site-verification content=_Jd4DyFIJ-LlvrfYl7nq9VsJGU0Dl-fSewUtb8xFY1M><meta name=google-site-verification content=22lwQj3aZEg4S0p9e0z4t561wEmGC5q1u3yxbu7qAC8><meta name=google-site-verification content=R674rCopA_NzCaJ7A72UfmTkpXBUyudgh0a4u_JznQE><meta name=google-site-verification content=86eWgZxBzwHcvvnNMA8WPOAxjOOesyMvyQBzz3BW3BQ><meta name=mailru-verification content=2be7cbd6459741ed><meta name=yandex-verification content=1737294911c38a7a><meta name=yandex-verification content=c1a636f058f5aae4><meta name=yandex-verification content=12e93a30f6213678><meta name=mailru-verification content=67628f3035f4dc15><!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/icons/favicon.ico"><![endif]--><meta name=theme-color content=#E53935><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=white><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-title content=KazanExpress><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/static/img/icons/apple-touch-icon.png><link rel=mask-icon href=/static/img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg color=#e53935><meta name=msapplication-TileImage content=/static/img/icons/mstile-144x144.png><meta name=msapplication-TileColor content=#FFF><script nomodule type=text/javascript src=https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js defer=defer></script><link rel=stylesheet href=/static/css/styleoff.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/static/css/fonts.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/static/css/typebase.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/static/css/helpers.css><script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=default-3.6,fetch" defer=defer></script><script>(
    function(w,d,s,l,i) {
      w[l]=w[l]||[];
      w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
      });
      var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),
      dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KTRMJ4R');</script><script type=text/javascript src=https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?158 onload="function onload() { VK.Retargeting.Init('VK-RTRG-1007905-4evhc'), VK.Retargeting.Hit() }"></script><script type=text/javascript>// Just in case
    if (!window.VK) {
      window.VK = {}; VK._protocol = 'https:'; VK._base_domain = ''; if (!VK.Retargeting) { VK.Retargeting = { pixelCode: null, Init: function (pixelCode) { this.pixelCode = pixelCode; return this }, Event: function (event) { if (!this.pixelCode) { return } (window.Image ? (new Image()) : document.createElement('img')).src = 'https://vk.com/rtrg?p=' + this.pixelCode + (event ? ('&event=' + encodeURIComponent(event)) : '') }, Hit: function () { this.Event() }, Add: function (audienceID) { if (!this.pixelCode || !audienceID) { return } (window.Image ? (new Image()) : document.createElement('img')).src = 'https://vk.com/rtrg?p=' + this.pixelCode + '&audience=' + encodeURIComponent(audienceID) } } };
    }
    VK.Retargeting.Init('VK-RTRG-1007905-4evhc');
    VK.Retargeting.Hit();</script><noscript><img src="https://vk.com/rtrg?p=VK-RTRG-1007905-4evhc" style="position:fixed; left:-999px;" alt=""></noscript><script type=text/javascript>!function(){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0,t.src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?168",t.onload=function(){VK.Retargeting.Init("VK-RTRG-547218-gUAWw"),VK.Retargeting.Hit()},document.head.appendChild(t)}();</script><noscript><img src="https://vk.com/rtrg?p=VK-RTRG-547218-gUAWw" style="position:fixed; left:-999px;" alt=""></noscript><script defer=defer src=/static/js/app.3d0e36da4f33b0696aa2.js?55e750b3c45d2da95e4e></script></head><body><app></app><noscript><div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;transform: translateY(50vh);transform: translateY(calc(50vh - 50%));"><svg id=Layer_1 data-name="Layer 1" xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg viewBox="0 0 76.73 76.88" style="width: 36px;height: 36px;"><defs><style>.cls-1 {
              fill: #e53935;
            }</style></defs><title>KazanExpress</title><path class=cls-1 d=M56.06,53.61H47.74L35.36,37.88h0L47.51,23.27h8.31L45.94,35.15H76.73a38.44,38.44,0,1,0,0,6.58h-30Zm-23.12,0H26.36V23.27h6.58V53.61Z></path></svg><p>Пожалуйста, включите JavaScript, чтобы воспользоваться сайтом!</p></div></noscript><script type=text/javascript>var _tmr = window._tmr || (window._tmr = []);
    _tmr.push({id: "3210365", type: "pageView", start: (new Date()).getTime()});
    (function (d, w, id) {
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      var ts = d.createElement("script"); ts.type = "text/javascript"; ts.async = true; ts.id = id;
      ts.src = "https://top-fwz1.mail.ru/js/code.js";
      var f = function () {var s = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ts, s);};
      if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") { d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false); } else { f(); }
    })(document, window, "topmailru-code");</script><noscript><div><img src="https://top-fwz1.mail.ru/counter?id=3210365;js=na" style=border:0;position:absolute;left:-9999px; alt=Top.Mail.Ru></div></noscript><script type=text/javascript>var axel = Math.random() + "";
    var a = axel * 10000000000000;
    document.write('<iframe src="https://9943304.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=9943304;type=visitors;cat=kazan0;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;tfua;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');</script><noscript><iframe src="https://9943304.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=9943304;type=visitors;cat=kazan0;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;tfua=; ord=1?" width=1 height=1 frameborder=0 style=display:none></iframe></noscript><script>mindbox = window.mindbox || function() { mindbox.queue.push(arguments); };
    mindbox.queue = mindbox.queue || [];</script><script>mindbox('create', { endpointId: 'kazanexpress-website' });</script><script src=https://api.mindbox.ru/scripts/v1/tracker.js async></script><noscript><div><img src="//top-fwz1.mail.ru/counter?id=3052180;js=na" style=border:0;position:absolute;left:-9999px; alt=""></div></noscript><script type=text/javascript>!function () { var t = document.createElement("script"); t.type = "text/javascript", t.async = !0, t.src = "https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?158", t.onload = function () { VK.Retargeting.Init("VK-RTRG-1007905-4evhc"), VK.Retargeting.Hit() }, document.head.appendChild(t) }();</script><noscript><img src="https://vk.com/rtrg?p=VK-RTRG-1007905-4evhc" style="position:fixed; left:-999px;" alt=""></noscript><noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KTRMJ4R" height=0 width=0 style=display:none;visibility:hidden></iframe></noscript><link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" preload></body></html>
```

So as you can see by clicking this url: https://kazanexpress.ru/product/736692

that html code is not that i need and when i open it its just a white screen.
How can i get real html code?

Comment: The link you provided worked fine for me

Comment: Of course it is the actual HTML. BUT, you won't find any "HTML you need" in there. Why? Because the document is altered through Javascript. The HTML you get is the HTML the browser gets. The browser will then execute the scripts which will add elements to the document tree. You should take a look at browser puppeteering to find what you want. For example selenium.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ordinary HTML page, it has JS embedded in the page code. This code is executed after the page is accepted and is used to fetch the page rendered by the server, so you need to make other requests to GET the information in the page, just to name a few.

```
https://api.kazanexpress.ru/api/v2/product/736692
```

This is a temporary URL for the data generated by the server, and it may be invalid when you click on it, but you can see the data in here.

```html
{"payload":{"data":{"id":736692,"title":"Смартфон realme C11 2021 2+32GB (NFC)","category":{"id":12690,"title":"Смартфоны","productAmount":183,"parent":{"id":10044,"title":"Смартфоны и телефоны","productAmount":41925,"parent":{"id":10020,"title":"Электроника","productAmount":66655,"parent":null}}},"rating":4.9,"reviewsAmount":18,"ordersAmount":226,"rOrdersAmount":200,"totalAvailableAmount":14,"charityCommission":0,"description":"<h1 class=\"ql-align-center\">Смартфон realme C11 2021</h1><p class=\"ql-align-center\"><img src=\"https://image-cdn.kazanexpress.ru/c8bkdcghmedd7lh3b2ug/original.jpg\"></p><p class=\"ql-align-center\"><a href=\"https://kazanexpress.ru/product/Avtomobilnoe-zaryadnoe-ustrojstvo-704090\"><img src=\"https://image-cdn.kazanexpress.ru/c8bkhr8knioe95m0nghg/original.jpg\"></a><a href=\"https://kazanexpress.ru/product/Chekhol-knizhka-universalnyj-dlya-703999\"><img src=\"https://image-cdn.kazanexpress.ru/c8hk4c5irr08a1l3sf40/original.jpg\"></a><a href=\"https://kazanexpress.ru/product/Zaschitnoe-steklo-Gresso-594030\"><img src=\"https://image-cdn.kazanexpress.ru/c981b927dhhsgj7hmirg/original.jpg\"></a></p><h1 class=\"ql-align-center\">Смартфон realme C11 2021 2+32</h1><p class=\"ql-align-center\"><img src=\"https://moneyfromnothing.ru/phones/realme-c11-2021/pics/realme-c11-2021.jpg\"></p><p class=\"ql-align-center\">Realme C11 2021 – стильный смартфон с производительным процессором Octa Core и ёмкой батареей для активных пользователей.</p><p class=\"ql-align-center\"><img src=\"https://sw.cool3c.com/user/29442/2021/f02eeee4-7f34-4cce-aeb6-2e7a0a8907a0.jpg?fit=max&amp;w=1400&amp;q=80\"></p><h1 class=\"ql-align-center\">ВСЕГДА НА СВЯЗИ</h1><p>Запаса в 5000 мАч благодаря опции суперэнергоэффективности хватает на срок до 43 дней при использовании режима ожидания, до 38 часов разговоров и до 19 – при просмотре фильмов и клипов нон-стоп. Функция реверсивной зарядки позволит восполнять ресурс аккумулятора внешних устройств с беспроводным интерфейсом, например смарт-часов или наушников.</p><p class=\"ql-align-center\"><img src=\"https://img.blogs.es/realme/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Abre_realmeC11-1080x675.jpeg\"></p><h1 class=\"ql-align-center\">БОЛЬШЕ УДОВОЛЬСТВИЯ</h1><p>Иммерсивный HD+ экран диагональю 6,5 дюймов создаёт эффект полного погружения в картинку. Соотношение сторон 20:9 оптимально для разного мультимедийного контента. Возможностей основной камеры на 8 Мп с поддержкой HRD хватает для съёмки чётких видео при движении, детализированных панорам и качественных портретов с распознаванием лиц. Бьютификация обеспечивает красивые и естественные селфи.</p><p><br></p><h1 class=\"ql-align-center\">ВСЁ ПОД РУКОЙ</h1><p>В тройном слоте есть модули для двух SIM и одной microSD. Объём памяти 2+32 Гб можно расширить за счёт дополнительной карты до 256 Гб – этого достаточно, чтобы не думать о том, хватит ли места для фото, игр и приложений.</p>","comments":[],"attributes":["Диагональ экрана: 6.52\"","Объем памяти: 2Гб оперативная, 32Гб встроенная","Тройной слот: 2 SIM + 1 MicroSD","Версия ОС: Android 11 Go","Количество ядер: 8","Частота работы процессора: 1.6 ГГц","Количество мегапикселей камеры: 8 Мп, 5 Мп","NFC: Да"],"tags":[],"synonyms":[],"photos":[{"photo":{"800":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/original.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_low.jpg"},"720":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/original.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_low.jpg"},"480":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_540_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_540_low.jpg"},"240":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_240_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_240_low.jpg"},"80":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_80_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_80_low.jpg"},"24034":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_240_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_240_low.jpg"},"120":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_240_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_240_low.jpg"},"540":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_540_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_540_low.jpg"},"60":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_80_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn69prp4amo508f80/t_product_80_low.jpg"}},"photoKey":"carvn69prp4amo508f80","color":"#0549be","hasVerticalPhoto":false},{"photo":{"800":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/original.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_low.jpg"},"720":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/original.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_low.jpg"},"480":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_540_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_540_low.jpg"},"240":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_240_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_240_low.jpg"},"80":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_80_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_80_low.jpg"},"24034":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_240_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_240_low.jpg"},"120":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_240_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_240_low.jpg"},"540":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_540_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_540_low.jpg"},"60":{"high":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_80_high.jpg","low":"https://ke-images.servicecdn.ru/carvn79slg8l47n5976g/t_product_80_low.jpg"}},"photoKey":"carvn79slg8l47n5976g","color":"#000000","hasVerticalPhoto":false}],"video":null,"hasCircularPhotos":false,"circularPhotosList":[],"characteristics":[{"id":-1,"title":"Цвет","values":[{"id":-125,"title":"Синий","value":"#0549be"},{"id":-1,"title":"Черный","value":"#000000"}]}],"productOptionDtos":[],"skuList":[{"id":1973578,"characteristics":[{"charIndex":0,"valueIndex":0}],"availableAmount":2,"fullPrice":10490.00,"charityProfit":0.00,"purchasePrice":7990.00,"barcode":6941399045385,"address":null,"offer":null,"discountBadge":null,"installment":{"payment":1331.67,"monthAmount":6},"productOptionDtos":[],"vat":{"type":"NONE","vatRate":0,"vatAmount":0.00,"price":7990.00}},{"id":1973579,"characteristics":[{"charIndex":0,"valueIndex":1}],"availableAmount":12,"fullPrice":10490.00,"charityProfit":0.00,"purchasePrice":7990.00,"barcode":6941399045392,"address":null,"offer":null,"discountBadge":null,"installment":{"payment":1331.67,"monthAmount":6},"productOptionDtos":[],"vat":{"type":"NONE","vatRate":0,"vatAmount":0.00,"price":7990.00}}],"seller":{"id":5491,"title":"texnikaprо","link":"texnikapro","banner":null,"avatar":null,"description":"Дарим ПРОМОКОД на смарт-часы и фитнес браслеты при покупке смартфона от 10.000р в нашем магазине! \n(*Акция действует только после доставки смартфона)\n\nНаша компания работает с 2000 года.\nНа данный момент в сети 87 салонов связи и продолжают открываться новые. \nМы являемся официальными дистрибьюторами крупнейших брендов электроники на территории Российской Федерации.\nВсе наши товары являются продуктами с сертификацией РОСТЕСТ и ЕАС, с официальной гарантией производителя.\nПриятных покупок.","hasCharityProducts":false,"registrationDate":1633609649320,"rating":4.6,"reviews":3607,"orders":41605,"official":false,"contacts":[],"categories":[],"currentCategory":null,"filters":[],"appliedFilters":[],"priceFilter":null,"totalProducts":0,"parents":[],"products":[],"sellerAccountId":2975961,"info":null},"topFeedback":{"reviewId":1484280,"productId":736692,"date":1629135570249,"edited":false,"customer":"Евгений","reply":{"id":619572,"date":1629276520205,"edited":true,"content":"Благодарим Вас за выбор нашего магазина и за высокую оценку товара. Мы очень рады, что вы остались довольны покупкой. В нашем магазине большой выбор качественной электроники и аксессуаров, ознакомиться с ассортиментом можно по следующей ссылке https://kazanexpress.ru/texnikapro . Мы всегда к Вашим услугам, ждем Вас снова!","shop":"texnikaprо","photos":[],"liked":null,"disliked":null},"rating":5,"characteristics":[{"characteristic":"Цвет","characteristicValue":"Черный"}],"pros":null,"cons":null,"content":"Сегодня в 5:20 был совершён заказ, сегодня ж вечером телефончик ждал меня в пункте выдачи. Спасибо продавцу за оперативность.","photos":[],"status":"PUBLISHED","hasVerticalPhoto":null,"like":false,"dislike":false,"amountLike":0,"amountDislike":0,"id":29108868,"isAnonymous":false},"isEco":false,"isPerishable":false,"hasVerticalPhoto":true,"showKitty":false,"bonusProduct":false,"badges":[],"volumeDiscount":null,"colorPhotoPreview":true,"adultCategory":false,"favourite":false},"promotion":null},"timestamp":[2022,7,17,18,6,27,148297000]}
```

As you can see, it is a string of data in JSON format, and when the JS code retrieves the data it will display it on the page, not in HTML.